# Calling common methods just once in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I've existing code in ASP.net MVC app which returns my device count as shown below:

```
        return (from device in mynetwork.Devices where Helper.IsDevAvailable(device.id) != true
                select new DeviceInfo
                {
                    id = device.DeviceId,
                    name = BuildDeviceName(device),
                    make = Helper.GetListValue(device.List).Contains('_') ? (Helper.GetListValue(device.List).Split('_')[1] == Type.Unknown.ToString() ? "NA" : Helper.GetListValue(device.List).Split('_')[1]) : "NA"
                }).Count();
```

Here, GetListValue is a function which gets invoked multiple times due to the way its written in above code.

I'm new to .NET & would like to know if there a way to call this GetListValue just once & modify above code in some way to improve performance & thus avoiding unnecessary multiple calls to this function in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`let`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) keyword

```
return (from device in mynetwork.Devices
        where Helper.IsDevAvailable(device.id) != true
        let listValue = Helper.GetListValue(device.List)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        select new DeviceInfo
            {
                id = device.DeviceId,
                name = BuildDeviceName(device),
                make = listValue.Contains('_') ? (listValue.Split('_')[1] == Type.Unknown.ToString() ? "NA" : listValue.Split('_')[1]) : "NA"
            }).Count();
```

Comment: why someone has given -1 vote? Is this not correct approach? lastr2d2 also suggested same soln

Answer (score 2):

This is already answered, but here is the same thing with chained syntax without using the let keyword.

I wanted to throw this out there just to show you how to do it when your using chained linq calls "as let is only available with a linq query syntax".

```
        mynetwork.Devices.Where(device => !Helper.IsDevAvailable(device)).Select(device =>
        {
            var listValue = Helper.GetListValue(device.List);
            return new DeviceInfo()
            {
                id = device.deviceId,
                name = BuildDeviceName(device),
                make = listValue.Contains('_') ? (listValue.Split('_')[1] == Type.Unknown.ToString() ? "NA" : listValue.Split('_')[1]) : "NA"
            };
        }).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [let clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx)

```
from xxx
let tempValue = Helper.GetListValue(device.List)
select xxx
```

Comment: Can u tell me in this example how it'll look like?

Comment: @FreephonePanwal just add `let tempValue = Helper.GetListValue(device.List)` before your `select new`  and use this `tempValue` in select